# Nested conditions in where clause of OSLC

Tags: clearquest, oslc

Are nested conditions possible in `WHERE` clause of OSLC?

Ex : 
`oslc.where=(name="James" and age>25 and (operatingStatus=null or operatingStatus="Active") )`

If not, what is the way to extract using such nested `WHERE` condition?
Am new to OSLC. Any help will be extremely useful.

Comment: I don't see the relation to SPARQL here? What's the reason for the tag?

Comment: Sorry.. i'm very new to OSLC and it's used by very few people compared to other technologies. So in a desperate attempt i tagged expecting someone using SPARQL who also knows OSLC may have the answer for my question.

Comment: So in order to get more attention, you added some tags that have nothing to do with the question? I don't think that this is "best practice"...especially not, since there are explicit mailing lists for OSLC: https://open-services.net/mailman/listinfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you look at https://open-services.net/bin/view/Main/OSLCCoreSpecQuery#oslc_where under the Syntax section:

```
oslc_where    ::= "oslc.where=" compound_term
compound_term ::= simple_term (space? boolean_op space? simple_term)*
simple_term   ::= term | scoped_term
```

As you can see, `compound_term` does not allow further compound terms. You should use SPARQL queries for more advanced scenarios such as yours.